# RegEx: Extracting string between optional single or double quotes on optionally multiple lines from Jekyll posts

Tags: regex, batch-file, jekyll, batch-processing

I need some expert help.

I'm extracting post titles from Jekyll YAML *"frontmatter"* metadata.

I spent about half a day on this, and still can't get the regex right.

```
Data & expected result (ER):

### simple cases ###

title: "aaa 123"
ER: aaa 123
title: 'bbb 123'
ER: bbb 123
title: ccc 123
ER: ccc 123

### quotes inside ###

title: 'aaa "abc" 123'
ER: aaa "abc" 123
### apostrophes, multiple lines
title: "aaa bbb'ccc ddd,
123"
ER: aaa bbb'ccc ddd, 123

### multiple lines

title: "aaa bbb
123"
ER: aaa bbb 123
title: 'aaa bbb
123'
ER: aaa bbb 123
title: aaa 123
ER: aaa bbb 123

### multiple lines quotes inside

title: 'aaa "123" "abc" "123"
ccc'
ER: aaa "123" "abc" "123" ccc
```

https://regex101.com/r/hO0aF7/3

I'm using JREPL.bat (http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044).

## UPDATE

Just to be clear. I have this:

```
---
layout: post
title: 'aaa post title bbb'
date: '2010-03-15T22:24:00.012Z'
author: xxx
tags:
- xxx
modified_time: '2013-03-24T04:11:54.224Z'
---

xxx
```

I want this:

```
aaa post title bbb
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the expected result? Provide a [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj41KOw18XOAhUGmBoKHUX-B-4QFghNMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=-8Zxs3rzB_bNuxuQ8U-DoQ)

Comment: Updated question with *expected result*.